# sql order by based on two columns values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

| ID | name | src |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sundaresh | 1111 |
| 2 | altos | 2222 |
| 3 | anand | 1111 |
| 4 | gautham | 3333 |
| 5 | mahindra | 1111 |
| 6 | Tata | 3333 |
| 7 | Narayan | 3333 |
| 8 | Satya | 1111 |
| 9 | Shiv | 2222 |
| 10 | Ratan | 2222 |

As I have mentioned in the above table I need to retrieve the results   as below. (for example 'name' column to be filtered in ascending order along with similar 'src' column)

| ID | name | src |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | altos | 2222 |
| 10 | Ratan | 2222 |
| 9 | Shiv | 2222 |
| 3 | anand | 1111 |
| 5 | mahindra | 1111 |
| 8 | Satya | 1111 |
| 1 | sundaresh | 1111 |
| 4 | gautham | 3333 |
| 7 | Narayan | 3333 |
| 6 | Tata | 3333 |

able to retrieve data by similar 'src' column and corresponding 'name' column in ascending order

```
SELECT * From Table Order by src,name ASC
```

Comment: Can please explain the logic behind the sorting I don't get it

Comment: Me too, why is 1111 after 2222 but before 3333?

Comment: The logic seems to be "order by name, but add all rows with same src directly after the first one with that value". So `altos` `anand` and `gautham` are ordered by name. But before `gautham` add all rows which have the same value as `altos`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySql 8.0+ you can do it with `MIN()` window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY MIN(name) OVER (PARTITION BY src), 
         name
```

For previous versions use a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
ORDER BY (SELECT MIN(t2.name) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.src = t1.src), 
         name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e268a5ae0a5269c70442eb46adbf9ad8).
Results:

| ID | name | src |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | altos | 2222 |
| 10 | Ratan | 2222 |
| 9 | Shiv | 2222 |
| 3 | anand | 1111 |
| 5 | mahindra | 1111 |
| 8 | Satya | 1111 |
| 1 | sundaresh | 1111 |
| 4 | gautham | 3333 |
| 7 | Narayan | 3333 |
| 6 | Tata | 3333 |